# Angular Service for storing a variable does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got an angular module called service.

Basically, I need to call function from another Controller and get an array that it'll return.

So I created a service for that. I'm calling function of `ControllerTwo` inside `ControllerOne` and this function puts data into service's variable `serviceTwolist`. After that I'm accessing this variable in `ControllerTwo`.

But my variable `allData` that supposed to be a return of a call of a function `getListTwo()` is "undefined".

Can somebody explain what's wrong?

```
var service = angular.module('service', ['datatables']);

service.service('serviceTwo', function () {
    this.serviceTwolist = [];

    this.returnList = function () {
        return serviceTwolist;
    }
});

service.controller('ControllerOne', ['$http', '$scope', '$stateParams', '$rootScope', 
'serviceTwo', function ($http, $scope, $stateParams, serviceTwo) {

    $scope.crossData = function () {
        $scope.$emit('getListTwo');
        var allData = serviceTwo.serviceTwolist;
        .....
    }};   

service.controller('ControllerTwo', ['$http', '$scope', '$stateParams', 'serviceTwo', 
function ($http, $scope, $stateParams, serviceTwo) {
 $scope.$on('getListTwo', function () {
    $http.get(*******).then(
        function success(response) {
            serviceTwo.serviceTwolist = response.data;
        },
        function error(data) {
            console.log(data);
            window.alert(data.data.message);
        }
    );
});
```

**promise attempt #1** Failed

```
$scope.crossData = function () {

 var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $scope.$emit('getListTwo');
    });
    var allData = [];

    promise.then(function (result) {
        allData = serviceTwo.serviceTwolist;
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
 ....
```

**promise attempt #2** (via Andrei Dragotoniu) Failed

```
 $scope.crossData = function () {

    this.promiseMethod = function () {

        var deferred = $scope.$emit('getListTwo');
            data = serviceTwo.serviceTwolist;

        deferred.resolve(data);
        return deferred.promise();
    };

    promiseMethod().then(function (someData) {
        allData = servicetwo.serviceTwolist;
    });
 ....
```

I've done something wrong, didn't I?

Comment: The code assumes that calling `$scope.$emit('getListTwo')` will assign `serviceTwo.serviceTwolist` synchronously, while it will not. This is what the promises are there for.

Comment: @estus, can you give me a catch how to use a promise here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http call is async, after the controllertwo receives the event getListTwo and fires the http request it does not wait for the success of the http call. You should wait for the call to complete to update the allData.

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at what you've got there, I think that ControllerTwo should be doing the emit so that ControllerOne be aware that the service has been filled?  Also, ControllerOne should be calling serviceTwo.returnList(), or just get rid of that method if unnecessary.

Comment: What does it mean ControllerTwo should be doing the emit? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, just simplified it a bit. works fine for me. Here's what I did :

js :

```
(function () {
    var service = angular.module('service', []);

    service.service('serviceTwo', function () {
        this.serviceTwolist = [];

        this.returnList = function () {
            return serviceTwolist;
        }
    });

    service.controller('ControllerOne', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 
    'serviceTwo', function ($scope, serviceTwo) {

        $scope.crossData = function () {
            $scope.$emit('getListTwo');
            var allData = serviceTwo.serviceTwolist;            
        }

        $scope.$on('getListTwo', function () {
            serviceTwo.serviceTwolist = { data: 1 };
        });
    }]);

})();
```

all you have to do in your html is to trigger the crossData method.

I put together a simple html so show that working :

```
<body ng-app="service" ng-controller="ControllerOne">    
    <button ng-click="crossData();">Go</button>   
</body>
</html>
```

triggers fine for me.

Now if you need to wait for a service call to return data and then do something then yes use a promise as others suggested. Here's an example of a promise :

```
this.promiseMethod = function () {

        var deferred = $.Deferred(),
            data = some service call

        deferred.resolve(data);
        return deferred.promise();
    };
```

to use it you then do something like :

```
promiseMethod().then(function (someData) {
   do something here
});
```

Comment: well actually I trigger crossData method with ng-click, but it stil doesn't work. Maybe @estus right, and I need to use promises?

Comment: ok, I added more info to my reply, showing how to do a promise.

Comment: thanks, I tries to use your code, but it just didn't happen :)

Comment: then I suggest to learn how to use JavaScript promises, it will fix your issue. My code was supposed to start you on that path, not provide fully functional code.